# Ionic having multiple files for services and controllers

Tags: ionic-framework

Usually by default in Ionic Framework there is a single file that all services are stored and a single file that all controllers are stored.

But this on big projects may turn out with hard to maintain and develop code.Is there a way to split the code of controllers and services into smaller easily maintainable files?

I already have this project: https://github.com/pc-magas/faster And I want from the start to set it Into a Mentainable form.

Answer (score 1):

Along with suggestions from above user, you can even bundle all your JS using gulp task and include that single file in index.html. This will ensure you don't miss out any file inclusion in index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Angular Best Practices](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. I would recommend that you take a look at the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project. In their code, they have separated their services and controllers into separate files.

Basically, what you have to do is separate the files and then include them in your app.js, like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'myApp.controller1',
  'myApp.controller2'    
])
```

And then above your controller, you have to put something like the following:

```
angular.module('myApp.controller1', [])

.controller('Controller1Ctrl', [function() {

}]);
```

Lastly, you need to include the controller, service or directive in your index.html, like this:

```
<script src="folder/controller1.js"></script>
```

It is up to you to decide how you want to structure your files. Here is an [article](http://artandlogic.com/2013/05/ive-been-doing-it-wrong-part-1-of-3/), in which the author outlines some ways to structure AngularJS projects.